# Summation of series involving complex exponents.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

> I am interested to find out what is $\sum_{k=0}^{200} i^k$, where $i$ is complex number

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: Do you know how to sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You may use the standard [geometric series identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nz^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z},\quad z\neq1,
$$ giving
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{200}i^k=\frac{1-i^{201}}{1-i}.
$$ Then simplify $1-i^{201}$ using $i^2=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Look at the sequence of partial sums.

$1$

$1+i$

$1+i-1$

$1+i-1-i$

$1+i-1-i+1$

$1+i-1-i+1+i$

$\vdots$

> simplify each to see the pattern:  $(1,1+i,i,0,1,1+i,i,0,\dots)$

Comment: Thanks all of you. It is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $i$ is the imaginary unit. Note that for all $k \in \mathbb N_0$
$$\begin{align*}
i^{4k} &= 1 \\
i^{4k+1} &= i \\
i^{4k+2} &= -1 \\
i^{4k+3} &= -i
\end{align*}$$

In particular $i^{4k}+i^{4k+1}+i^{4k+2}+i^{4k+3} = 1 + i -1 -i = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb N_0$.

Now $\sum_{k=0}^{200} i^k = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{49} i^{4k}+i^{4k+1}+i^{4k+2}+i^{4k+3} \right) + i^{200} = 0 + i^{4 \cdot 50} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint summation of four continuous powers of $i=0$ now $200$ is divisible by $4$ hence summation of all the powers till $200$ is $0$. And $i^0=1$ thus $\sum =1$